# Using Dask to read parquet files from a google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, parquet, dask, pyarrow

I'm trying to use Dask to read and write from a google bucket.
Using a bunch of `csv` files works, but is inconvenient (slower, can't compress, can't have the ability to read only some columns) so I tried using the `apache parquet` format.

The writing seems to work fine:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [2,3, 2], 'y': [1, 0, 0]})
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=2)
dask_df.to_parquet("gcs://my_google_bucket/test/")
```

But when I try to read it back

```
read_again_df = dd.read_parquet("gcs://my_google_bucket/test/")
```

I get a non implemented error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py in get_pyarrow_filesystem(fs)
    520     try:
--> 521         return fs._get_pyarrow_filesystem()
    522     except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'DaskGCSFileSystem' object has no attribute '_get_pyarrow_filesystem'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-ef1fc41d04d5> in <module>()
----> 1 read_again = dd.read_parquet("gcs://my_google_bucket/test/")

~/miniconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, infer_divisions)
    991 
    992     return read(fs, fs_token, paths, columns=columns, filters=filters,
--> 993                 categories=categories, index=index, infer_divisions=infer_divisions)
    994 
    995 

~/miniconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py in _read_pyarrow(fs, fs_token, paths, columns, filters, categories, index, infer_divisions)
    505         columns = list(columns)
    506 
--> 507     dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(paths, filesystem=get_pyarrow_filesystem(fs))
    508     if dataset.partitions is not None:
    509         partitions = [n for n in dataset.partitions.partition_names

~/miniconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py in get_pyarrow_filesystem(fs)
    522     except AttributeError:
    523         raise NotImplementedError("Using pyarrow with a %r "
--> 524                                   "filesystem object" % type(fs).__name__)

NotImplementedError: Using pyarrow with a 'DaskGCSFileSystem' filesystem object
```

I'm guessing this means that `dask` still can't read parquet files from google cloud service directly.
Is there any indirect way of making this work with, say, using `pyarrow`?

What I want to keep is the ability of lazy loading things and then using `dask` to do data transformations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dask can certainly read parquet from GCS with the fastparquet backend (`engine='fastparquet'`). Note that pyarrow will not have made the `_metadata` file that fastparquet expects, so you can either write your data with fastparquet, create the file from the existing data files using fastparquet, or pass a glob-string pointing to all of the data files instead of the directory.

What you are doing ought to work with pyarrow too, as pyarrow can generally accept any python file-like object, but in this case appears to be trying to make a pyarrow-filesystem instead. The error you are seeing above is likely a bug and should be investigated.

-edit-

According to comments from the OP, the following does work

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [2,3, 2], 'y': [1, 0, 0]}) 
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=2) 
dask_df.to_parquet("gcs://my_bucket/test", engine='fastparquet') 
read_again_df = dd.read_parquet("gcs://my_bucket/test/", engine='fastparquet')
```

Please note that, for some buggy reason, `dask_df.to_parquet()` needs to be called with "gcs://my_bucket/test", without the "/", otherwise the `dd.read_parquet()` doesn't work

Comment: thanks! I'll try writing and then reading with `engine='fastparquet'` and update this question appropriately.

Comment: Can you update your question to include this? I'll accept it then. The following works!
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [2,3, 2], 'y': [1, 0, 0]})
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=2)
dask_df.to_parquet("gcs://spike-kwik/test", engine='fastparquet')
read_again_df = dd.read_parquet("gcs://spike-kwik/test/", engine='fastparquet')

Please note that  it has to be "gcs://spike-kwik/test" and not "gcs://spike-kwik/test/", otherwise it doesn't work!

Comment: I have included your code lines. Please check and edit as you see fit @cd98 .

Comment: done! I opened up an issue on `dask` too: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4009